# "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" error when printing array values in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I don't understand why I get the error "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" when I try to run this code. I though this error only occurred when you don't have a numpy array, but I do.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to print out lists, when you actually want to print floats. I believe you're looking for:

```
print("x: %5.2f y: %5.4f" %(x_list[i], y_list[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print line is trying to cast the entire list of values of x_list and y_list to floats. Instead, you should print each element individually.

Your last line should be:

```
print("x: %5.2f y: %5.4f" %(x_list[i], y_list[i]))
```